# Processing - /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups failed

Tags: printing

I am running ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop at work and cannot manage to have our printer to work.

Setting up the printer either with the GUI or with cups (webbrowser) is working fine but no chance with printing anything since I get the error message 
"Processing - /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups failed"

Background:
The print server we have is running openSuse with CUPS 1.5.4
my saucy ubuntu has cups 1.7rc1

The IT here want to mess with my computer and downgrade cups to 1.5.4 ... :-/

I already tried to reinstall all cups, hplip, and various dependencies with no luck ... and tried using different driver versions

Any suggestions ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I meet this weird problem, too. After trying all kinds of methods, the problem is finally resolved by using latest hplip. You can download 3.14.4 from http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/gethplip.html and then execute the .run file.